# Pass an array as parameter in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, argument-passing, mailer

I'm trying to do a diffusion (where you send an email to a lot of users).
So in my model (with mongodb)

```
key :email, Array
```

In my controller:

```
@users = params[:user]
@emails = Array.new
@users.each do |user|
  @emails << User.find_by_username(user).email
end
```

So in the link I pass as argument the array:

```
<%= link_to "Create a diffusion", mailer_path(:user => User.all)%>
```

In my form:

```
<%= f.input :email, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @emails } %>
```

The problem is in my mailer:

```
@message.email.each do |email|
  mail(:to => email, :subject => @message.subject)
end
```

The problem is that @message is not an array, is a string.
So that loop will be an once-loop.
I've tried also do @message.email.split(",") but doesn't work.
I think it would be great if @message would be an array (how it should be)

Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to add `:multiple => true` to your input?

Comment: even if I put that, is just an string was I'm passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it!
The problem was that I wasn't passing an array, the solution is in the form. the new form should be like:

```
<% @emails.each do |email| %>
  <%=f.input "email[#{email}]", :as => :text, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => ""} %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're naming is somehow reflecting the objects you are dealing with, maybe you should try:

```
@emails.each do |mail|
  mail(:to => mail, :subject => @message.subject, ...)
end
```

and why not:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  mail(:to => user, :subject => @message.subject, ...)
end
```

Comment: @emails doesn't work in that scope (I put the new action, no create action, so actually is my fault).
User.all.each is not good because I want the same mailer for a message to one single user too.

Comment: Couldn't you use then something like: `@recipients = whatever_set_of_users_you_want`, and iterate through it?

Comment: finally the main problem was that I didn't parsing all the elements, and I should pass as an array, so I couldn't do anything in the controller.
Thank you anyway :)